# Add custom checkbox to woocommerce_checkout_order_review

Tags: wordpress, checkbox, woocommerce, checkout

I have been scratching my head all day. I would like to add a custom checkbox within order review before placing order. Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'my_checkbox' );

function my_checkbox( $checkout ) {
    echo '<div class="my_split_checkbox"><h2>' . __('Split Order', 'woocommerce') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_split_checkbox', array(
        'type'     => 'checkbox',
        'class'    => array('checkbox_field'),
        'label'    => __('Split Order', 'woocommerce'),
        'required' => false,
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_split_checkbox' ));

    echo '</div>';
}
```

but the page doesn't fully load. However if I replace the hook by

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'my_checkbox' );
```

then the chekbox shows at the end of billing details with no issues. How can I get the textbox to show within checkout order review? Ideally after table .woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use any of those below hooks instead of `woocommerce_checkout_order_review` to show the checkbox field based on your priority-

```
woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents
woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping
woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping
woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total
woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total
```

For further information go to `woocommerce/templates/checkout/review-order.php`. If you already copied the `templates` folder as `woocommerce` to your theme directory then may be you'll find the `review-order.php` there. And also you need to remove `$checkout` variable as well as `, $checkout->get_value( 'my_split_checkbox' )`. Cause those hooks do not pass any parameter. Please check the `review-order.php`, you'll get an overview.

So your whole code will be like below-

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'my_checkbox' );

function my_checkbox() {
    echo '<div class="my_split_checkbox"><h2>' . __('Split Order', 'woocommerce') . '</h2>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_split_checkbox', array(
        'type'     => 'checkbox',
        'class'    => array('checkbox_field'),
        'label'    => __('Split Order', 'woocommerce'),
        'required' => false,
    ));

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for quick reply. I have tried all the hooks you have mentioned but all of them stop loading rest of page once they reach `woocommerce_form_field`. I have all my functions in functions.php

Comment: Turn on your ***WordPress*** debug mode by doing `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` at your `wp-config.php` and give here the error.

Comment: I get **Fatal error: Call to a member function get_value() on string** which leads to `), $checkout->get_value( 'my_split_checkbox' ));` why would the variable $checkout be an issue?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. And if the answer helps you then please accept the answer by checking the check sign on the left side of the answer. @Alex

Comment: If the answer helps you then please accept the answer by checking the check sign on the left side of the answer. @Alex